# Inserting count and sum functions

Tags: php

Here is what my code prints:

```
 Even numbers: 2 4 6
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$names = file('file.txt');
echo "Text: ";
foreach($names as $name)
{
echo $name . "</br>";
}
echo "Even numbers: ";
foreach ($names as $name) {

$name = count_chars( $name, 3);
for($i=0; $i<strlen($name);$i++) {
    if (is_numeric($name[$i]) && $name[$i]%2==0)
    { 
echo $name[$i];
    }
    }
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Could someone tell me how should I count all of these values into the new line (I need to get an answer 3) and get those values sum (I need to get 12)? I know I have to use count and sum functions, i don't know exactly where. Thanks for any help. All the answer should look like this:

```
Even numbers: 2 4 6
Even numbers are: 3
Even numbers sum are: 2 + 4 + 6 = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$names = file('file.txt');
echo "Text: ";
foreach($names as $name)
{
echo $name . "</br>";
}
echo "Even numbers: ";
foreach ($names as $name) { 
$count = 0
$evens = [];
$name = count_chars($name, 3);
for($i=0; $i<strlen($name);$i++) {
    if (is_numeric($name[$i]) && $name[$i]%2==0)
    { 
     $count++;
     $evens[] = $name[$i];
     echo $name[$i];
    }
    }
echo "<br>";
}


echo "Even numbers Are: " . $count;
$i=0;
foreach($evens as $e){ 
   $i++;
   if($i == count($evens)){
     $evens_string .=  $e . '=' ;
   } else {
     $evens_string .= $e . '+' ;
   }
}

$even_string .= array_sum($evens);

echo "Even numbers sum are: " . $even_string;
```

Hope this gives you the idea! I have not tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your question.
But I think `array_sum` is what you are looking for. (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Below is my code for your reference:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value%2)) {
        $even[] = $value;
    } else {
        $odd[] = $value;
    }
}

echo 'Even numbers: '.implode(' ', $even).'<br>';
echo 'Odd numbers: '.implode(' ', $odd).'<br>';
echo 'Even numbers sum are: '.implode(' + ', $even).' = '.array_sum($even);
```